# Power BI Custom OpenStreetMap Visual

Tags: powerbi, openstreetmap, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

i want to create a custom visual map on power-bi by using openstreetmap.
Therefore i created a new visual project as : `pbiviz new LeafletCustomVisual`

after that i install osm as : `npm install osm --save`
and edited `pbiviz.json` as

```
"externalJS": [
"node_modules/osm/index.js"
],
```

also i checked out https://www.npmjs.com/package/osm page and tried on `visual.ts` as:

```
import osm from 'osm';
export class Visual implements IVisual {

  private map: osm;
  constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
      this.target = options.element;
      this.map = osm().position(47.88038, 10.6222475);
      this.target.appendChild(this.map.show());
    }
}
```

but i just didnt work.i am not familiar with node.js and related stuff